# Leak on appendFormat

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm using instruments to detect some leaks and there's some leaks I can't resolve;

```
        NSMutableString *textedetails = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];   ------->2,3%
                if([dico objectForKey:@"alertSerie"] != nil)
                    {[textedetails appendFormat:@"Numéro de Série: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertSerie"]];}
                if([dico objectForKey:@"alertDate"] != nil)
                    {[textedetails appendFormat:@"Date de mise en service: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertDate"]];}
                if([dico objectForKey:@"alertCli"] != nil)
                    {[textedetails appendFormat:@"Nom du client associé: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertCli"]];}     ------->20,9%

                NSMutableString *texterecap = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];------->2,3%
                if([dico objectForKey:@"alertIndex"] != nil)
                {[texterecap appendFormat:@"Index du Compteur: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertIndex"]];}
                if([dico objectForKey:@"alertE2day"] != nil)
                {[texterecap appendFormat:@"Energie produite aujourd'hui: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertE2day"]];}
                if([dico objectForKey:@"alertEmo"] != nil)
                {[texterecap appendFormat:@"Energie produite ce mois-ci: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertEmo"]];}
                if([dico objectForKey:@"alertEy"] != nil)
                {[texterecap appendFormat:@"Energie produite cette année-ci: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertEy"]];}
                if([dico objectForKey:@"alertCO"] != nil)
                {[texterecap appendFormat:@"CO2 économisé cette année: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertCO"]];}
                if([dico objectForKey:@"alertPerfRel"] != nil)       
                {[texterecap appendFormat:@"Performance relative: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertPerfRel"]];}      ------->74,4%

    [dico release];
details.numberOfLines=0;    // Pour mettre le nombre de lignes possibles à infini.
        details.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textedetails ];
        recapitulatif.numberOfLines=0;
        recapitulatif.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", texterecap ];

        [textedetails release];
        [texterecap release];
```

...

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [login dealloc];
    [motdepasse dealloc];
    [responseData dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And here :

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login et Mot de passe" message:@"Votre login et votre mot de passe sont enregistrés."delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];[alert release]; ------> 100%
```

I don't understand those leaks and howto resolve them!

Thanks to help me :D

**EDIT :**

Apparently, the leak for the alertview isn't a leak.

For the first leak, there is a leak again !!!

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, it seems to me that you are not releasing two variables: `textedetails` and `texterecap` (at least, you are not doing it in the code shown).  It is not clear what you are doing next with those strings (assigning to properties?), if you show some more code I might be able to help you further.

Your `dealloc` method is quite not right; it should be:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [login release];
    [motdepasse release];
    [responseData release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I don't know if this could also solve what instruments is reporting, since it is pretty unusual calling `dealloc` on an object (i.e., I don't know what effects it could have).

Furthermore, it seems that you are not releasing `recapitulatif`.

In the second case, the alert view is not being dismissed correctly, I guess. The code is correct; I would only try and implement the delegate protocol to see if the `– alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:` method is actually called.

Comment: and how can I dismiss it? is there a special method to implement? (there is no action to perform, it is just an alert)

Comment: login and motdepasse cannot be released there; they are variable of the method ;-)

Comment: don't understand... you are calling `dealloc` on them within the `dealloc` method. what does that mean that they are variable of the method? there seems to be something that is not right, don't know whether in the post or in the code...

Comment: I made lots of release on the dealloc method but "texterecap" still leak :-/

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are alloc/initing two NSMutableStrings without calling release on them. The UIAlertView usage looks ok.

Try using the [Analyze](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/static-code-analysis-clang-and-xcode-3-2.html) function in Xcode. It will point out where the leaks are occurring and explain why.

Comment: I release the strings at the end of the method. I will check analyse ;-) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you really want NSMutuableString

you could have used

```
NSString *textedetails;;
NSString *texterecap;
if([dico objectForKey:@"alertSerie"] != nil){
    [textedetails stringByAppendingFormat:@"Numéro de Série: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertSerie"]];
}
if(....){}
details.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textedetails ];
recapitulatif.numberOfLines=0;
recapitulatif.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", texterecap ];


** this is autoreleased instance, so you do not need to call explicitly release on them **
```

> you need to release only those object which is created by using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

and in your second question, if you would have passed the delegate as self, would not be leak i guess.
   (according to your comment) i think some thing wrong then, because the below code for alert view will never leak.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login et Mot de passe" message:@"Votre login et votre mot de passe sont enregistrés." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: I hope the above code will fix the leak for your second question

Comment: there is again a leak (the two vars are NSMutable I think.. and for the Alert, it still leak again...

Comment: Ohh sorry, my mistake, there was typo, i have edited it. are you running that piece of code in loop.

Comment: I cannot use a NSString because I use "appendFormat"... I have to use a NSMutableString otherwise it doesn't work! (NSString may not respond to -appendFormat )

Comment: Who say you can not do with NSString do you know about stringByAppendingFormat ( http://bit.ly/pXCaS3 ). see my edited answer.

Comment: NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURLConnection stringByAppendingFormat:]

Comment: as i can see your edit comment, now there is no leak for your alertview, [NSURLConnection stringByAppendingFormat] this is another issue(**not related to this issue**) NSInvalidArgumentException is the error when you are passing the valid object but you are passing invalid object.

Comment: I only use stringByAppendingFormat for "NSString *texterecap;" as you said but it doesn't working (end I don't know if there is a leak on it) ...

Comment: Why its not working? show us your code. just use http://pastebin.com or http://dpaste.com and paste your code over there and send me link.